# Spring Boot Kafka Consumer throwing No bean named 'kafkaListenerContainerFactory' available

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mobicule</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-kafka-consumer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>spring-boot-kafka-consumer</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**KafkaConfiguration.java**

```
package com.mobicule.springbootkafkaconsumer.config;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory;

@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory()
    {
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group_id");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);


        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, String>(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaConsumerFactory()
    {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String>();

        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }



}
```

**KafkaConsumer.java**

```
package com.mobicule.springbootkafkaconsumer.listener;

import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class KafkaConsumer {

    @KafkaListener(topics="ConsumerDemo",groupId="group_id")
    public void consume(String message)
    {
        System.out.println("In kafka consumer "+message);
    }

}
```

I have configured Basic Kafka Producer project using Spring Initializer (without server)

1) I produced a message "Hello World" on topic "ConsumerConfig" using terminal
   Then when i executed my consumer project i got error as

```
The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
    - Bean method 'kafkaConsumerFactory' in 'KafkaAutoConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory; SearchStrategy: all) found beans of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory' consumerFactory
    - User-defined bean method 'consumerFactory' in 'KafkaConfiguration'


Action:

Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory' in your configuration.
```

So i searched and i got a link which said put 
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = KafkaAutoConfiguration.class)

Even after putting the above in my code i got an error as
Description:

```
A component required a bean named 'kafkaListenerContainerFactory' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'kafkaListenerContainerFactory' in your configuration.
```

What am i missing here ? Do i need to do anymore configurations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Spring Boot, you don't need that custom `ConsumerFactory`, neither `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory`. You should fully rely on the auto-configuration and appropriate configuration properties from the `spring.kafka` namespace: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-kafka

If you still insist to exclude `KafkaAutoConfiguration` and do everything manually, you really need to name your `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` with the requested `kafkaListenerContainerFactory` bean name: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#kafka-listener-annotation

Comment: I referred an youtube video :-  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IncG0_XSSBg . In that video he has defined custom Consumerfactory and ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory  .It worked , why not mine ?

Comment: The difference is here in there `@KafkaListener` annotation: `containerFactory()` - `<p>If not specified, the default container factory is used, if any.`